# Laravel (4.1.24) Array to string conversion when pass query output to view

Tags: arrays, view, laravel

I'm trying to built a simple application in Laravel (4.1.24). But I have a problem when I try to use the data from a query in a view.

method:

```
    public function openExcersise(){
    $data = Auth::user();
    $levels = DB::table('user_levels')->where('user_id', $data->id)->get();
    //var_dump($levels);
    return View::make('users.excersise_home', array('title'=>'excersise', 'data'=>$data, 'levels'=>$levels));
}
```

view:

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')

<section class="container registration">
    <div class="row center">
        <h1>Hi, {{ $data['firstname'] }}</h1>
        @include('embeds.userErrors')
    </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p>excersise</p>
        <!--{{$data}}-->
        {{$levels}}
    </div>
</section>

@endsection
```

error:

ErrorException
Array to string conversion (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/flashwords/app/app/views/users/excersise_home.blade.php)

When I dump $levels in the method I get the following output (which is right from content, I need one record and I get one)

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#172 (9) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["1"]=> string(0) "" ["2"]=> string(0) "" ["3"]=> string(0) "" ["4"]=> string(0) "" ["5"]=> string(0) "" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2014-03-23 19:33:53" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2014-03-23 19:33:53" } }
```

I have no idea what's going wrong, because I can use the $data var without any problems in the view which is also an array so...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$data` without any problems because it is an **object** implementing the [ArrayAccess interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php), and also providing a [magical `__toString` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring). In other words: it is **not** an array...